# How to find all calls incompatible with iOS 7

Tags: xamarin

I'd like to find all iOS 7-incompatible calls in my app.

Is there a way to do that in Xamarin Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Xamarin Studio does not help you here.

The usual way of doing this is to run your app on an older simulator and see where it breaks...